# Getting locations of all the bus stops/metro stations for a path using google directions?

Tags: google-maps, directions

Is it possible to extract all possible metro stations/ bus stops from a path generated by google directions api? I want to know longt, latt of these stations, so that I can suggest the user about nearest transport facilities/ hubs based on the source and destination entered(along the path).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out google transit http://www.google.com/intl/en/landing/transit/#mdy which is a new service they are offering in select locations.

Comment: Thanks. that is exactly something that I wanted to develop. I also found this, http://journeyplanner.tfl.gov.uk/user/XSLT_TRIP_REQUEST2?language=en .

Comment: Same here, I was bummed when I saw google was in the business, after transcribing the local bus schedule here for an iphone app.